# leap motion first person controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am currently working on a leap motion game using Unity.
When I just to use the hand gesture to replace the traditional first person control which used the keyboard. I am able to walking through the wall with the leap motion controller. But when i use keyboard, it will just stop at the wall. I have added a collision box to the wall. But still i cannot fix the problems.

Below is my Leap Characters Controller script in C#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Leap;

public class LeapCharacterController : MonoBehaviour {

    Controller m_leapController;
    float m_lastBlastTime = 0.0f;

    GameObject m_carriedObject;
    bool m_handOpenThisFrame = false;
    bool m_handOpenLastFrame = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        m_leapController = new Controller();
    }

    // gets the hand furthest away from the user (closest to the screen).
    Hand GetForeMostHand() {
        Frame f = m_leapController.Frame();
        Hand foremostHand = null;
        float zMax = -float.MaxValue;
        for(int i = 0; i < f.Hands.Count; ++i) {
            float palmZ = f.Hands[i].PalmPosition.ToUnityScaled().z;
            if (palmZ > zMax) {
                zMax = palmZ;
                foremostHand = f.Hands[i];
            }
        }

        return foremostHand;
    }

    void OnHandOpen(Hand h) {
        m_carriedObject = null;
    }

    void OnHandClose(Hand h) {
        // look for an object to pick up.
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.SphereCast(new Ray(transform.position + transform.forward * 2.0f, transform.forward), 2.0f, out hit)) {
            m_carriedObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
        }
    }

    bool IsHandOpen(Hand h) {
        return h.Fingers.Count > 1; 
    }

    // processes character camera look based on hand position.
    void ProcessLook(Hand hand) {
        float handX = hand.PalmPosition.ToUnityScaled().x;
        transform.RotateAround(Vector3.up, handX * 0.30f);
    }

    void MoveCharacter(Hand hand) {
        if (hand.PalmPosition.ToUnityScaled().z > 0) {
            transform.position += transform.forward * 0.1f;
        }

        if (hand.PalmPosition.ToUnityScaled().z < -1.0f) {
            transform.position -= transform.forward * 0.04f;
        }
    }

    // Determines if any of the hand open/close functions should be called.
    void HandCallbacks(Hand h) {
        if (m_handOpenThisFrame && m_handOpenLastFrame == false) {
            OnHandOpen(h);
        }

        if (m_handOpenThisFrame == false && m_handOpenLastFrame == true) {
            OnHandClose(h); 
        }
    }

    // if we're carrying an object, perform the logic needed to move the object
    // with us as we walk (or pull it toward us if it's far away).
    void MoveCarriedObject() {
        if (m_carriedObject != null) {
            Vector3 targetPos = transform.position + new Vector3(transform.forward.x, 0, transform.forward.z) * 5.0f;
            Vector3 deltaVec = targetPos - m_carriedObject.transform.position;
            if (deltaVec.magnitude > 0.1f) {
                m_carriedObject.rigidbody.velocity = (deltaVec) * 10.0f;
            } else {
                m_carriedObject.rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        Hand foremostHand = GetForeMostHand();
        if (foremostHand != null) {
            m_handOpenThisFrame = IsHandOpen(foremostHand);
            ProcessLook(foremostHand);
            MoveCharacter(foremostHand);
            HandCallbacks(foremostHand);
            MoveCarriedObject();
        }
        m_handOpenLastFrame = m_handOpenThisFrame;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have rigid body of your shooter set and enabled from the editor?

Answer (score 1):

```
void MoveCharacter(Hand hand) {
        if (hand.PalmPosition.ToUnityScaled().z > 0) {
            transform.position += transform.forward * 0.1f;
        }

        if (hand.PalmPosition.ToUnityScaled().z < -1.0f) {
            transform.position -= transform.forward * 0.04f;
        }
    }
```

You are directly modifying the transform's position without any form of collision detection. If you want to use unity's colliders and physics engine you need to use the rigidbody for movement or if you want to stick with directly setting the transform's position you need to implement your own collision detection code (maybe raycasts or some such).

This issue covered in the unity docs here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html

and there is a how to vid on the learn site which looks into the movement via rigidbody here: http://unity3d.com/earn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/moving-the-player

Comment: Your solution helps me a lots. Thank you very much. Sorry for that late thanks!!!